# 特殊なCSV加工　python

Tags: python

### やりたいこと

元のCSVを実現したいCSVにするためにはどのようなpythonコードを書けば良いでしょうか。

#### 元のCSV(dataframeとします)

列A 列B 列C
10 20 30

#### 実現したいCSV

行数
1
列A. 列B 列C
10. 20. 30

列A、B、Cがあるにもかかわらず、行数という列名と値をその上に追加する。
（本来のCSVファイル形式ではない）

Comment: ラベルとなる ”列A” 等は除いた CSV の行数を取得して、元の CSV にデータとして追加したい…という事でしょうか？

Comment: 「元のCSV」読み書きは Pythonで作れますか？ 読み込んで DataFrame準備する処理。そして DataFrameをもとに「元のCSV」と同じ内容をファイルへ書き込む処理。作れるようなら 調査や試行錯誤として 質問文に載せるとよいかもです

Answer (score 0):

この記事が応用できると考えられます。
[Pandas の CSV に追加する](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/python-pandas/pandas-to-csv-append/)

> データを保存する上で興味深い機能として、パラメータ`a`を使った`append`モードがあり、これを使って既存の CSV ファイルにデータを追加することができます。

[pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

> mode : str
> Python write mode, default 'w'.

こんな風に2つのDataFrameを用意し、それぞれのDataFrameを別々に書き出して、2つ目をappendモードにすれば良いでしょう。

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1]], columns = ['行数'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30]], columns = ['列A','列B','列C'])

outfilename = 'combined.csv'

df1.to_csv(outfilename, index=False, encoding='utf8')
df2.to_csv(outfilename, mode='a', index=False, encoding='utf8')
```

まあ最初の2行はDataFrameでは無く、単なる2行のテキストファイルであっても良いわけですが。

Comment: ありがとうございました、解決しました。便利な機能があるんですね、知りませんでした。